# Связать 2 select

Tags: javascript, html

Вообще есть 2 select один просто и другой в модалке. Они абсолютно одинаковые различаются только классами. Мне нужно чтобы когда в одном из них выбрали options во втором select произошел такой же выбор. Это надо замутить на js. Я могу получить только выбранные элемент в select

```
$(".select_one").on('change', function () {
        var ids_op = this.selectedIndex;
}
```

но как его присвоить второму?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял(jQuery):

```js
$('.one').on('change', function() {
  $('.two').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='one'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<select class='two'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у нас разные окна c одного сайта, то используем localStorage. Классы как раз делаем одинаковые, либо добавляем одинаковые, чтобы работало в обе стороны с одним кодом.

```
$(".select").on('change', function () {
  const ids_op = this.selectedIndex;
  window.localStorage.setItem('ids_op', ids_op);
});

window.addEventListener('storage', e => {
  if (e.key === 'ids_op') {
    $(".select")[0].selectedIndex = e.newValue;
  }
});
```